# Что такое "партаки"?

Tags: этимология

Или портаки (как правильно)? Какова этимология данного слова?

Comment: Прошу прощения за свою необразованность, но поясните, пожалуйста, что это слово значит. Яндекс не помог.

Comment: От слова "портачить" ( напортить, испортить). "портаки, неудачные тату"

Comment: @yupaz, мой вопрос и заключался в том, что вообще значит это слово и от куда произошло такое название. 
@grumant, спасибо!

Comment: "Партаки" на фене - татуировка. То ли вообще всякая, то ли какой-то тип - не силён.

Comment: В обнаруженном мной словаре фени (не сетевом - бумажном) слово написано "портачка (портак) - неудачная татуировка".

Comment: Мнение девушки из сети : " Всерьёз задумываюсь о парочке
татуировок, но уже после рождения
второго малыша. Ну а
ксерокопирование 1-в-1 самых
распространённых надписей на своём
теле - это практически "партак" (или
"портак" - от слова портить), как
принято говорить на сленге
татуировщиков." Добавить более нечего.

Comment: Скорее всего индоевропейское - с большей вероятностью где-то в сторону Ирана/Индии искать следует (судя по звучанию).

Answer (score 1):

Этимологию стоит искать у русских слов. А партаки возводят к английскому partake (участвовать, разделять). Сомневаться у меня нет причин, слово явно нерусское. Пусть им англичане занимаются.

Есть правда, любители для любого слова на фене выискивать корни на идише, но я к ним не отношусь. При всей роли идиша (а через него - и иврита), сводить всё к нему нельзя. А значит, и "английская" версия вполне себе возможна.

Answer (score 1):

А уж если ты хорошо рисуешь, то стенгазета и «партаки» (наколки) сделают тебя поистине «золотым слоном». [Михаил ФАЛАЛЕЕВ, Александр КОЦ, Виктор БАРАНЕЦ. Как выжить первую неделю в казарме // Комсомольская правда, 2003.09.30]

Словцо «партаки» (наколка) вызывает ассоциации с парча (узор) и сиртаки (касание). Сложение начальных букв парч(а) и конечных (сир)таки дает "партаки". Впрочем, конечное "таки" могло произойти и от "тык(ать)".

Парча́. Считается др.-рус. заимств. из тюрк. яз., где парча «парча» < парча «узор». Парча буквально — «узорчатая ткань». (словарь Шанского Н. М.)

Версия образования «партаки» из смешения слов «портачить» и «art» кажется менее вероятной.

Слово «(на)портачить» образовано от портить, порча, а за тем - (в начале 20 века) портач. Убедимся на примерах, что слова «портач» и «портки» не родственны.

по́рча Из *pъrti̯a от по́ртить. (словарь Фасмера М.)

Слушай, Серошевский, этого твоего Островского нужно гнать со строительства в три шеи к чертовой матери вместе со всей его бригадой!.. Это не монтажники, а портачи. Спешат, путаются, ни черта не знают… [В. П. Катаев. Время, вперед! (1931-1932)]

Почему, наконец, у нас нет отдела контроля, который мог бы сказать разным педагогическим портачам: [А. С. Макаренко. Педагогическая поэма. Часть 3 (1935)]

Приедет Вальган и скажет: «Это не завод, это не я, это без меня главный инженер напортачил!» [Г. Е. Николаева. Битва в пути (1959)]

Answer (score -1):

Это от слова *портачить - портить*, потому что кожу себе портите.

Comment: Портачить и портить - этимологически разные слова. Не надо смешивать. Портачить - шить "порты" (портки, т.е. грубые штаны). Отсюда же портной. К порче прямого отношения не имеет.